# Complex problem: Error with organising information on a very large dataset

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, large-data, rolling-computation

I have two pandas dataframes. The first is called `df` that has a list of records of flights (saved in different columns: `stand, acreg, start_datetime,` and `end_datetime`).

For each record, there are many values in the column `"fpu_A"` in a second DataFrame called `df_fpu`. Note that `df_fpu` also has columns for these records, but these repeat themselves many times over (see small example below). The `df_fpu` DataFrame also has a column `"datetime"`.

For each record in `df`, I want to get the value from the column `"datetime"` in `df_fpu` where the current row, as well as the next 4 rows, have a value above 100 for `"fpu_A"`. I then want to save this datetime in a new column `"start"` in `df`.

The following code, gives the error: `KeyError: '[nan] not in index'`:

```
# Define a function to get the start datetime for each record
def get_start_datetime(group):
    # Only consider rows without np.nan values
    group = df_fpu.dropna(subset=["fpu_A"])
    # When no values, just skip this flight record
    if group.empty:
        np.nan 
        
    # Check if the current row and the next 4 rows have a value above 100 in column "fpu_A"
    if (group['fpu_A'].rolling(5).apply(lambda x: (x > 100).all())).any():
        # Get the datetime value corresponding to the first row in the sequence
        start_datetime = group.loc[group['fpu_A'].rolling(5).apply(lambda x: (x > 100).all()), 'datetime'].iloc[0]
        return start_datetime
    else:
        return np.nan

# Group the df_fpu dataframe by flight and apply the get_start_datetime function
df['start'] = df_fpu.groupby(["stand", "acreg", "start_datetime", "end_datetime"]).apply(get_start_datetime).reset_index(drop=True)

# Output the resulting dataframe
print(df)
```

The dataset is too large to use a `for` loop. Below are 50 rows of sample data for the following record from df:

| acreg | start_datetime | end_datetime | stand |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EIDEL | 2023-05-01T08:46:12.000+0000 | 2023-05-01T09:26:10.000+0000 | D24 |

In the actual dataset, there are 500 such rows for this one record and there are thousands of different records. In this example, I'd like to get the `datetime` of the fifth row which is `2023-05-01T00:04:00.000+0000`.

| datetime | acreg | start_datetime | end_datetime | stand | fpu_A |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-05-01T00:00:00.000+0000 | ZZZZZ | 2023-05-01T08:46:12.000+0000 | 2023-05-01T09:26:10.000+0000 | D24 | 32.78 |
| 2023-05-01T00:01:00.000+0000 | ZZZZZ | 2023-05-01T08:46:12.000+0000 | 2023-05-01T09:26:10.000+0000 | D24 | 31.93 |
| 2023-05-01T00:02:00.000+0000 | ZZZZZ | 2023-05-01T08:46:12.000+0000 | 2023-05-01T09:26:10.000+0000 | D24 | 31.3 |
| 2023-05-01T00:03:00.000+0000 | ZZZZZ | 2023-05-01T08:46:12.000+0000 | 2023-05-01T09:26:10.000+0000 | D24 | 43.16 |
| 2023-05-01T00:04:00.000+0000 | ZZZZZ | 2023-05-01T08:46:12.000+0000 | 2023-05-01T09:26:10.000+0000 | D24 | 128.36 |
| 2023-05-01T00:05:00.000+0000 | ZZZZZ | 2023-05-01T08:46:12.000+0000 | 2023-05-01T09:26:10.000+0000 | D24 | 132.47 |
| 2023-05-01T00:06:00.000+0000 | ZZZZZ | 2023-05-01T08:46:12.000+0000 | 2023-05-01T09:26:10.000+0000 | D24 | 143.86 |
| 2023-05-01T00:07:00.000+0000 | ZZZZZ | 2023-05-01T08:46:12.000+0000 | 2023-05-01T09:26:10.000+0000 | D24 | 118.93 |
| 2023-05-01T00:08:00.000+0000 | ZZZZZ | 2023-05-01T08:46:12.000+0000 | 2023-05-01T09:26:10.000+0000 | D24 | 130.32 |
| 2023-05-01T00:09:00.000+0000 | ZZZZZ | 2023-05-01T08:46:12.000+0000 | 2023-05-01T09:26:10.000+0000 | D24 | 132.08 |
| 2023-05-01T00:10:00.000+0000 | ZZZZZ | 2023-05-01T08:46:12.000+0000 | 2023-05-01T09:26:10.000+0000 | D24 | 137.87 |
| 2023-05-01T00:11:00.000+0000 | ZZZZZ | 2023-05-01T08:46:12.000+0000 | 2023-05-01T09:26:10.000+0000 | D24 | 130.65 |
| 2023-05-01T00:12:00.000+0000 | ZZZZZ | 2023-05-01T08:46:12.000+0000 | 2023-05-01T09:26:10.000+0000 | D24 | 142.35 |
| 2023-05-01T00:13:00.000+0000 | ZZZZZ | 2023-05-01T08:46:12.000+0000 | 2023-05-01T09:26:10.000+0000 | D24 | 129.71 |
| 2023-05-01T00:14:00.000+0000 | ZZZZZ | 2023-05-01T08:46:12.000+0000 | 2023-05-01T09:26:10.000+0000 | D24 | 130.8 |
| 2023-05-01T00:15:00.000+0000 | ZZZZZ | 2023-05-01T08:46:12.000+0000 | 2023-05-01T09:26:10.000+0000 | D24 | 142.92 |
| 2023-05-01T00:16:00.000+0000 | ZZZZZ | 2023-05-01T08:46:12.000+0000 | 2023-05-01T09:26:10.000+0000 | D24 | 138.9 |
| 2023-05-01T00:17:00.000+0000 | ZZZZZ | 2023-05-01T08:46:12.000+0000 | 2023-05-01T09:26:10.000+0000 | D24 | 132.16 |
| 2023-05-01T00:18:00.000+0000 | ZZZZZ | 2023-05-01T08:46:12.000+0000 | 2023-05-01T09:26:10.000+0000 | D24 | 142.03 |
| 2023-05-01T00:19:00.000+0000 | ZZZZZ | 2023-05-01T08:46:12.000+0000 | 2023-05-01T09:26:10.000+0000 | D24 | 130.23 |
| 2023-05-01T00:20:00.000+0000 | ZZZZZ | 2023-05-01T08:46:12.000+0000 | 2023-05-01T09:26:10.000+0000 | D24 | 129.92 |
| 2023-05-01T00:21:00.000+0000 | ZZZZZ | 2023-05-01T08:46:12.000+0000 | 2023-05-01T09:26:10.000+0000 | D24 | 131.74 |
| 2023-05-01T00:22:00.000+0000 | ZZZZZ | 2023-05-01T08:46:12.000+0000 | 2023-05-01T09:26:10.000+0000 | D24 | 139.17 |
| 2023-05-01T00:23:00.000+0000 | ZZZZZ | 2023-05-01T08:46:12.000+0000 | 2023-05-01T09:26:10.000+0000 | D24 | 131.68 |
| 2023-05-01T00:24:00.000+0000 | ZZZZZ | 2023-05-01T08:46:12.000+0000 | 2023-05-01T09:26:10.000+0000 | D24 | 142.59 |
| 2023-05-01T00:25:00.000+0000 | ZZZZZ | 2023-05-01T08:46:12.000+0000 | 2023-05-01T09:26:10.000+0000 | D24 | 118.62 |
| 2023-05-01T00:26:00.000+0000 | ZZZZZ | 2023-05-01T08:46:12.000+0000 | 2023-05-01T09:26:10.000+0000 | D24 | 131.58 |
| 2023-05-01T00:27:00.000+0000 | ZZZZZ | 2023-05-01T08:46:12.000+0000 | 2023-05-01T09:26:10.000+0000 | D24 | 142.11 |
| 2023-05-01T00:28:00.000+0000 | ZZZZZ | 2023-05-01T08:46:12.000+0000 | 2023-05-01T09:26:10.000+0000 | D24 | 130.25 |
| 2023-05-01T00:29:00.000+0000 | ZZZZZ | 2023-05-01T08:46:12.000+0000 | 2023-05-01T09:26:10.000+0000 | D24 | 138.59 |
| 2023-05-01T00:30:00.000+0000 | ZZZZZ | 2023-05-01T08:46:12.000+0000 | 2023-05-01T09:26:10.000+0000 | D24 | 143.49 |
| 2023-05-01T00:31:00.000+0000 | ZZZZZ | 2023-05-01T08:46:12.000+0000 | 2023-05-01T09:26:10.000+0000 | D24 | 130.93 |
| 2023-05-01T00:32:00.000+0000 | ZZZZZ | 2023-05-01T08:46:12.000+0000 | 2023-05-01T09:26:10.000+0000 | D24 | 129.85 |
| 2023-05-01T00:33:00.000+0000 | ZZZZZ | 2023-05-01T08:46:12.000+0000 | 2023-05-01T09:26:10.000+0000 | D24 | 141.84 |
| 2023-05-01T00:34:00.000+0000 | ZZZZZ | 2023-05-01T08:46:12.000+0000 | 2023-05-01T09:26:10.000+0000 | D24 | 130.73 |
| 2023-05-01T00:35:00.000+0000 | ZZZZZ | 2023-05-01T08:46:12.000+0000 | 2023-05-01T09:26:10.000+0000 | D24 | 126.95 |
| 2023-05-01T00:36:00.000+0000 | ZZZZZ | 2023-05-01T08:46:12.000+0000 | 2023-05-01T09:26:10.000+0000 | D24 | 184.26 |
| 2023-05-01T00:37:00.000+0000 | ZZZZZ | 2023-05-01T08:46:12.000+0000 | 2023-05-01T09:26:10.000+0000 | D24 | 130.67 |
| 2023-05-01T00:38:00.000+0000 | ZZZZZ | 2023-05-01T08:46:12.000+0000 | 2023-05-01T09:26:10.000+0000 | D24 | 130.22 |
| 2023-05-01T00:39:00.000+0000 | ZZZZZ | 2023-05-01T08:46:12.000+0000 | 2023-05-01T09:26:10.000+0000 | D24 | 130.97 |
| 2023-05-01T00:40:00.000+0000 | ZZZZZ | 2023-05-01T08:46:12.000+0000 | 2023-05-01T09:26:10.000+0000 | D24 | 129.99 |
| 2023-05-01T00:41:00.000+0000 | ZZZZZ | 2023-05-01T08:46:12.000+0000 | 2023-05-01T09:26:10.000+0000 | D24 | 127.32 |
| 2023-05-01T00:42:00.000+0000 | ZZZZZ | 2023-05-01T08:46:12.000+0000 | 2023-05-01T09:26:10.000+0000 | D24 | 130.31 |
| 2023-05-01T00:43:00.000+0000 | ZZZZZ | 2023-05-01T08:46:12.000+0000 | 2023-05-01T09:26:10.000+0000 | D24 | 131.07 |
| 2023-05-01T00:44:00.000+0000 | ZZZZZ | 2023-05-01T08:46:12.000+0000 | 2023-05-01T09:26:10.000+0000 | D24 | 129.62 |
| 2023-05-01T00:45:00.000+0000 | ZZZZZ | 2023-05-01T08:46:12.000+0000 | 2023-05-01T09:26:10.000+0000 | D24 | 142 |
| 2023-05-01T00:46:00.000+0000 | ZZZZZ | 2023-05-01T08:46:12.000+0000 | 2023-05-01T09:26:10.000+0000 | D24 | 131.03 |
| 2023-05-01T00:47:00.000+0000 | ZZZZZ | 2023-05-01T08:46:12.000+0000 | 2023-05-01T09:26:10.000+0000 | D24 | 138.89 |
| 2023-05-01T00:48:00.000+0000 | ZZZZZ | 2023-05-01T08:46:12.000+0000 | 2023-05-01T09:26:10.000+0000 | D24 | 131.11 |
| 2023-05-01T00:49:00.000+0000 | ZZZZZ | 2023-05-01T08:46:12.000+0000 | 2023-05-01T09:26:10.000+0000 | D24 | 129.7 |

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `.rolling()` function looks at the previous rows and not the next ones (as I thought it did). The following solves the problem (from the Python documentation):

```
# For five periods, set the size to 5
indexer = pd.api.indexers.FixedForwardWindowIndexer(window_size=5)
# Use the indexer object instead of the regular integer
df.rolling(window=indexer, min_periods=1).sum()
```